# Moving your Dropbox folder to a new location

Tags: nautilus, xfce, dropbox

I'm a Ubuntu user with an XFCE interface. I have installed such configuration in my desktop and notebook computers. But in the notebook, I can no longer use Dropbox since it asks me to move the folder to a compatible location.

If I try to move the folder to a different location, Dropbox tells me "To allow your Dropbox to sync, move your Dropbox folder to a partition with a compatible file system. Dropbox is compatible with Ext4 systems." But using the DIsk analyzer, I know such partition has Ext4 (version 1.0).

I have a ext4-formatted partition and [the docs](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/system-requirements#linux) say that it works in XFCE with the corresponding Nautilus dependencies. But it doesn't mention which are those dependencies, so I thin I may be missing one.

Can you help me? I really need to make this work and I don't want to use nautilus instead of XFCE since it is too heavy.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, Dropbox doesn't like LUKS Encryption. Although your root disk might be formatted as ext4, your home folder (presumably also home to the db folder) shows as LUKS, hence not ext4. You have many options; among them, separating your home and root folder (possible in typical debian installations.) and also moving dropbox to an external hard drive, formatted as ext4.